# Debezium oracle on confluent No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:oci

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

When i create kafka jdbc source connector(debezium connector for oracle with confluent-5.4.0),get errors "No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:oci...".

```
[2020-03-23 11:49:44,521] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=debezium-souce-inventory-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception ocurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.
    at io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue.throwProducerFailureIfPresent(ChangeEventQueue.java:170)
    at io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue.poll(ChangeEventQueue.java:151)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnectorTask.poll(OracleConnectorTask.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:oci:@test:1521/testdb
    at io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:179)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:83)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:oci:@test:1521/testdb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnectionFactory.connect(OracleConnectionFactory.java:25)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:756)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:751)
    at io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:119)
    ... 6 more
[2020-03-23 11:49:44,521] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=debezium-souce-inventory-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:180)
```

My oracle version is Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production,i have tried different driver jar but getting the same exception.

My jdk version is:

```
[root@vtsz-big-dwh02 /]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191
```

I have add debezium-connector-oracle to the folder confluent-5.4.0/share/java.

As the Debezium docs say, i install instant client and copy the files _ojbc8.jar and xtreams.jar from the Instant Client into Kafka's libs

directiry 
(`confluent-5.4.0/share/java/kafka` , `confluent-5.4.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc ,`/opt/confluent-5.4.0/lib`,`/usr/share/java`).

```
[root@vtsz-big-dwh02 java]# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/app/instantclient_11_2/:
```

My source connectors configuration is :

```
{
  "name": "debezium-souce-idea-inventory",
  "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
      "tasks.max": "1",
      "database.server.name":"testdb",
      "database.out.server.name":"testdb",
      "database.hostname": "10.0.10.169",
      "database.port": "1521",
      "database.user": "mytest",
      "database.password": "mytest",
      "database.dbname" : "testdb",
      "table.whitelist": "ideas.WMS_INVENTORY",
      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"localhost:9092",
      "database.history.kafka.topic":"schema-changes.inventory"
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the JAR files on which the connector (Debezium, in this case) depends *in the same folder (or subfolder) as the **connector plugin***.

So instead of putting them in

```
confluent-5.4.0/share/java/kafka
/opt/confluent-5.4.0/lib
/usr/share/java
confluent-5.4.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc
```

put them in

```
confluent-5.4.0/share/java/debezium-connector-oracle
```

(or wherever the actual Debezium JAR plugin resides)

Comment: as you said, i in put the JAR files in  
confluent-5.4.0/share/java/debezium-connector-oracle  
where the Debezium JAR plugin resides
but got the same error...

Comment: Did you restart the worker after doing this? Note that if you're running on Docker then when you restart the container any changes to the filesystem are lost, so you'd need to add the JAR in by mounting a volume or another method

Comment: this answer worked for me, I put the JAR in permanently by modifying the Debezium `Dockerfile` to also copy in the JAR to the `../debezium-connector-oracle` folder

Answer (score 0):

1. Debezium works with Oracle version 12 and 19. You are trying to use Oracle 11, very old version.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html#oracle-overview

2. From the URL: jdbc:oracle:oci, I would recommend switching to jdbc:oracle:thin and make sure you are using the correct jar compatible with Oracle 11.